# how can a patient with conduction aphasia answer questions but not repeat words?

Tags: neuroscience, vision

When we have a Q&A with someone, the path in the brain goes as such: auditory cortex to Wernicke's area (to be comprehended) which then activates the Broca's area to initiate a motor reaction (so to answer the questions). So if someone asks questions, is not the arcuate fascicle taken into use? Doesn't the Wernicke's somehow need to tell Broca what to say? Or does it just stop at Wernicke's and then a new path is initiated from Broca's?

When someone with conduction aphasia is asked to repeat a word, let's say "apple", they cannot as apparently this arcuate fascicle is necessary.

What is the difference with answering a question to repeating a word? Would the person be able to say "I cannot repeat the word 'apple'"? So it would technically be able to say the word 'apple'. Thanks in advance!